# trying to install gzip_static module for nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gzip

I have some Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instances with nginx installed, and am trying to enable the gzip_static module in order to serve precompressed assets.
I'm following instructions at https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/nginx-gzip_static-ubuntu.html

After I complete all the steps, I do nginx -v and still get

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

with no mention of the module being installed. The guide was written for an earlier version of nginx - does anyone know if the steps have changed or have any ideas how to remedy it? Thanks.

Comment: nginx-full (default nginx package on ubuntu) already contains gzip_static module

Comment: do `nginx -V 2>&1 | grep "\-\-with\-http_gzip_static_module"` to see if is installed already